# Is this possible in one SSH session? (BASH & PYTHON)

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

I'm writing a python script (on a Linux box) that will perform an SSH and run a string of commands on the remote machine (Sun-OS). I'm having trouble getting the remote commands to run and give expected output and I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Depending on the syntax I use, sometimes I get : "ksh: 28317 Segmentation Fault(coredump)"

If this is not possible, but it is using a different method in either python or at the CLI, please let me know.

Thanks!

```
ssh user@remote_machine "/dvs/dncs/bin/tellDhct -h mempoll/mempoll_lowmem_ips.out | awk '{print $1}' > mempoll/mempoll.macs && /dvs/dncs/bin/tellDhct -h mempoll/mempoll_nonresp_ips.out | awk '{print $1}' >> mempoll/mempoll.macs"
```

Comment: Can you run that huge command as is at ksh prompt on the remote machine?

Comment: @serge Yes..works without a problem.

Comment: The command seems made of 2 commands linked with a `&&`. Can you execute separately those commands through `ssh` with or without the final redirection to a file (`> mempoll/mempoll.macs` or `>> mempoll/mempoll.macs`) (divide and conquer exploratory method...)

Comment: @ serge.. Actually, I'm not even getting the output of the first command on the local terminal (the machine I'm SSH'ing from) even without the redirect.  When I do use the redirect, it creates the file, but it's empty. It works when I ssh directly into the remote machine. Not sure why that is, but looks like I need to start looking a little further back.

Comment: yes, it is possible. Run `ssh` as any other program e.g.,  `subprocess.check_call(['ssh', 'localhost', 'date +%Y | grep -o 20'])` What is your specific issue?

Comment: What is this command `/dvs/dncs/bin/tellDhct`? Some processes behave differently when run from a terminal or when run through pipes...

Comment: You have to account for all intervening interpretation of the command line. Here the $1 is interpreted on the local machine by the shell and replaced by white space before ssh sends the command to the remote machine. To prevent this, you must escape it : \$1. Notice that if you replace double quotes by single quotes, you would still have the problem with the remote shell that would interpret $1 before executing awk. (How many times have I been in this trap...)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
ssh user@remote << EOT
echo "test"
echo "you can put here anything like in a bash script"
echo "and it should work"
EOT
```