# Performing second SSH within SSH in perl

Tags: linux, git, perl, ssh

I have to perform a SSH from remote machine in which I've logged in using Net::SSH::Perl i.e. the 'cmd' passed to $ssh->cmd in the below code is another SSH(say username@hostname). Is there a way to pass the password for this second SSH and then execute command on this second remote machine.
Also, I cannot use tools like ssh key-pair logins or sshpass. Can someone help?

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;

    my $hostname = "hostname";
    my $username = "username";
    my $password = "password";

    my $cmd = <command to be executed on remote machine>;

    my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("$hostname", debug=>0);
    $ssh->login("$username","$password");
    my ($stdout,$stderr,$exit) = $ssh->cmd("$cmd");
    print $stdout;
```

Comment: I recall a related question.  Do you really have to do this, ssh in chains? Why not drop back to host and ssh from it again?

Comment: SSH to second remote machine can only be done from first remote machine

Comment: See also [Quoting in bash and perl in recursive ssh command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597777/quoting-in-bash-and-perl-in-recursive-ssh-command)

Comment: There should be possibility to create chain ssh command using method from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961937/is-this-possible-in-one-ssh-session-bash-python/35991359#35991359

Answer (score 2):

Net::SSH::Perl is seriously limited. I propose you would use [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-OpenSSH-0.70/lib/Net/OpenSSH.pm) instead if possible. It supports proxy command and tunnels which make it easy to use [jump host](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts).

If Net::SSH is your only option, then I'm afraid that the only way to do it is to use some sort of expect-like behaviour e.g. Net::SSH::Expect.